# Query Distinct Struct Attributes on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a struct in BigQuery where I need to select all distinct combinations of a certain struct attributes.

E.g.
Struct Person has Age, Gender, Country

I need to query all the possible Age, Gender, Country combinations there is for each Person Struct. Is there a way to do it in BigQuery? I've tried making a CTE to make the attributes as columns then do a DISTINCT() query but I can't get them out of the struct class.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT Person.Age, Person.Gender, Person.Country FROM my_table)

SELECT DISTINCT(cte.Age, cte.Gender, cte.Country) FROM CTE
```

I've tried this query but I still end up with this error `Column 1 of type STRUCT cannot be used in SELECT DISTINCT at [13:12]`

Comment: I think I can use GROUP BY but not sure if there are alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is not a function and `(cte.Age, cte.Gender, cte.Country)` is a struct literal, so `DISTINCT(cte.Age, cte.Gender, cte.Country)` is treated same as `DISTINCT STRUCT(cte.Age, cte.Gender, cte.Country)` and returns the error what you've got.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#struct_literals

Instead, you can try below.

```sql
WITH my_table AS (
  SELECT STRUCT(10 AS Age, 'M' AS Gender, 'US' AS Country) Person UNION ALL
  SELECT AS STRUCT 10 Age, 'M' Gender, 'US' Country UNION ALL
  SELECT AS STRUCT 20 Age, 'F' Gender, 'KR' Country
)
SELECT DISTINCT Person.* FROM my_table;
```

[image]

or if you want the output as a struct,

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(Person) AS Person FROM my_table
 GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', Person);
```

[image]